# How to obtain US Bachelor degree based on my old university credentials?

Tags: graduate-school, undergraduate, degree, education, bachelor

I learned a math course in a Russian university many years ago. For silly discrimination and other silly reasons I didn't finish it and didn't receive any diploma.

Recently (2020 Oct 27) I have confirmed my education by the US standards: 100.50 semester hours of undergraduate credit, grade Point Average is 3.54 based on a 4-point scale with A=4, B=3, C=2, D=1, F=0.

I want to receive the US Bachelor in mathematics. What can I do? Can I do it without passing any additional courses/exams? How much may it cost?

Note that despite of having no funding and no access to libraries and scientific databases I did a very advanced math research (some of which is peer reviewed and published). Essentially, I am a PhD with lost diploma.

Comment: Marginally relevant: [Pure maths “dropout” wanting to finish MSc thesis](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/159477/49593)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No real US university will award a degree to a student who has not taken any courses at that university.  What you want is not possible.

To award a degree, you must earn credits from the university.  Typically, this is at least half the total credits required for the degree.

Comment: "No real US university will award a degree to a student who has not taken any courses at that university." _Why_ do the devil servants behave this way?

Comment: @porton Because a university degree is a certification by the university that the holder of that degree has certain knowledge.  The way the university makes certain of that is by requiring students to take and pass *their* courses before awarding degrees.  By the way, calling people "devil servants" is not likely to make them want to help you.

Comment: @BobBrown By the way no human (except of my girlfriend) thinks about helping me anyway, so how could it harm?

Comment: @porton  I note that three people who have never met you have attempted to help you with the question you asked.

Comment: @BobBrown They exactly admitted that they could not help me.

Answer (score 2):

> Recently (2020 Oct 27) I have confirmed my education by the US standards: 100.50 semester hours of undergraduate credit

A typical diploma in the US is 120 semester hours. So, you're a bit short.

Be aware, however, that each school will make its own determination as to which classes can be transferred. Typically, they will look at the syllabus and determine which classes are comparable (this may be difficult in your case). So it is not at all guaranteed that a given school will count all 100 hours.

Further, virtually all schools have a "residence requirement." Even if they agree that all 100 hours are equivalent, they may not allow you to transfer more than, say, 90 hours. The thinking is that if you are going to earn a degree from University X, you should take a significant number of classes at University X. Otherwise, students could do all their coursework at school X and get the degree from school Y.

Finally, note that there are usually "distribution requirements" -- despite your plans to major in math, you will have to take classes in many subjects to earn a degree. I do not know whether this is also true in the Russian system.

> How much may it cost?

Thirty credits would probably cost about $10,000. This will vary hugely depending on the school you attend and the financial aid you qualify for.

> Note that despite of having no funding and no access to libraries and scientific databases I did a very advanced math research (some of which is peer reviewed and published).

Understood, but unfortunately it is difficult to convert non-University work into a degree. On the other hand, some employers might (wisely) overlook the lack of a degree.

> What can I do?

If finishing the degree at the Russian institution is still possible, that would probably be fastest and cheapest. Failing that, I would look for a reputable, local university with a generous policy on transfer credits. Other answers have also suggested some accredited online schools; this may be a good option as well.

Comment: "If finishing the degree at the Russian institution is still possible, that would probably be fastest and cheapest." I have a big conflict with Russia, so learning in Russia (and the only option would be to start paid studies from the first year) may probably be impossible or even dangerous. In fact, I deprived Russia of economic and military might: I did a fundamental scientific discovery and I am so much hated that they will be likely unable to cite my research, so a component in Russian education and science will be missing, leading to stop of the entire system. They may be offended.

Comment: By the way, I am almost sure I have been noticed by Putin when I told about my situation: He many times hinted (or were it not Putin but a spirit speaking through him?) that I am welcome to Russia. He forgot to give me email to write to and to pay for the air tickets, etc. Finally, I decided to try to cut the knot and told about their situation, harshly mocking the Russian way in a letter to Putin. Putin has recently reacted by splitting citizens to "ours" (and therefore "not ours") and advertising drinking alcohol to separate non-drinkers from "ours". Yes, it _is_ silly.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer to the question is *almost* universally true, [Excelsior College](https://www.excelsior.edu/) is a non-profit, regionally-accredited institution whose primary mission is to help students complete their degrees.  They don't offer a degree in mathematics, but *may* allow you to obtain a degree that would permit you to enter a U.S. graduate program.  If you are able to get an official transcript from your former institution, Excelsior College might be able to help.

Comment: I think, it is of little utility for me. I have already started a computer science study in UoPeople online university, it costs me one time $60 and $20 or $37 per course. (Yes, it is a real university in the sense that they do teach advanced topic and assess students strictly enough, so their degree would be reasonably counted valuable.) I see no reason why Excelsior College would be better: the most suitable course there seems to be Bachelor of Science in Information Technology and I don't see how it would be better than the courses I have started to take recently.

Comment: I viewed their website and it appears they do require courses and/or exams.  So this does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist  Of course, you are right in both your comment and your accepted answer.  My own answer is in aid of helping OP achieve his apparent goal of a recognized U.S. degree.  I'm going to leave it in case it is of help to others in the future.